# How can I get a value from SQL where each column occurs?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called comments with the columns: `posID` and `commentLikes`.

```
   tableComments

|  postID   | commentLikes |
+-----------+--------------+
|  233      |      2       |
|  233      |      0       |
|  675      |      2       |
|  345      |      12      |
|  345      |      8       |
```

In my PHP code, I am passing the PostID variable to my function.
I want to get the number of likes for each post based on postID passed into the function so I will need the WHERE clause.

I have tried using **COUNT** and **GROUP BY** but still no luck. So I need to count each time the postID matches a value and then add up the total number of likes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a single `postID` you don't need a `group by` clause, you just need to use it in the `where` clause and `sum` the likes:

```
SELECT SUM(likes)
FROM   tableComments
WHERE  postId = ?
```

The "?" should of course be bound from the PHP code.

Comment: What row should I return? $row['valueToReturn];

Comment: @RomeoHennessy this query returns a single line, with a single column - `$row[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `GROUP BY` since you will filter the records passed on the `POstId` you are passing.Just do a summation on the records you will get the desired results.

```
SELECT SUM(commentLikes)
FROM comments 
WHERE postID=@PostID
```